# Arabic characters corrupt on landing, fine after refresh - UTF8

Tags: php, html, utf-8, arabic

I have an php page with mixed Latin and Arabic characters. The charset declaration tag is in the html code

and the file is saved as UTF-8. All the text is static and in the php file (does not come from a DB or an external source)

When I browse to the site some pages randomly get corrupt in IE and FF and display all question marks. After I refresh the page, text is displayed properly though... I have been working with Arabic and Hebrew for a long time and this is the first time I run in to this issue. Can anybody think of a cause?

Chrome is always fine...

Comment: What happens when you manually change the encoding - using View -> Character Encoding?

Comment: also, did you make sure that your browser is caching the pages?

Comment: @ Matjis View -> Character Encoding already displays the proper encoding - utf-8. That's what puzzles me as usually the problem is due to the missing charset declaration which leaves a gap and the browser guesses one. In my case, the browser is set to the correct encoding but the page displays all ????????.

@Shreef - yes, I made sure it is not due to caching. If I keep refreshing the page, it goes back to the question marks every once in a while...

Comment: Curious. Even if the browser dropped the ball on the encoding it should still have seen valid characters in a national code page rather than an all-bad string of `??????`. I guess it's time to break out the network sniffer and see what actual bytes are being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the script reference that was before the meta description was causing the problem. I moved
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
 to be the first item after the opening head tag and this is no longer an issue. Thanks for all the comments..

P.S I wasn't the one who code this page, and only working on localizing it, thats why I didn't even think that meta tag being after script would even make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Try to send appropriate header, something like this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF8_encode on your content:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have some text you want to store in a DB and display even if the page encoding is latin-1, there is a free tool that can convert Unicode to escaped HTML:

http://www.sprawk.com/tools/escapeUnicode